# How to generate random "visually pleasing" 2D matrices given a range of blocks?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, layout

I am wondering sort of how to generate random user avatar designs, sort of like how StackOverflow default user avatars are, except I would just be dealing with squares. The range is anywhere from 21 to 137 possible squares in a design, and the design can be no longer than 13 squares and no thinner than 3 squares, the number of squares must be odd on each row, and there can be no gaps in the middle of rows. That is, each row is a solid line of 3 to 13 blocks.

What is the best way to randomly generate a bunch of designs? Is there a way to make them "visually pleasing" somehow, without hardcoding each one? How would you go about doing this so as to not have to manually place each block in a grid into the desired position?

For example, this is one idea:

```
        池池池
      池池池池池
        池池池
  池池池池池池池池池池
    池池池池池池池池
        池池池
```

This is another idea:

```
    池池池池池
    池池池池池
    池池池池池
    池池池池池
```

There are let's say 100 possible block sets from 21 to 137 in length. So I would think you could generate all the designs in advance (maybe a few thousand), and then just pick from the list as you go through so you never repeat.

Maybe perhaps there are wave patterns this could be designed after even...

```
function generateSquare(size) {
  
}

function generateTree(size) {
  
}

function generateBow() {
  return [
    [1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1],
  ]
}

function generateHourglass(size) {
  
}

function generate(size) {
  
}
```

Basically how can I generate these other than manually?

```
function generateBowA() {
  return [
    [1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1],
  ]
}

function generateBowA() {
  return [
    [1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1],
  ]
}

function generateBowB() {
  return [
    [1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1],
  ]
}

...
```

Or somehow like:

```
var set = [
  [3, 5, 7, 5, 3],
  [3, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3],
  [3, 5, 7, 5, 3, 5, 7, 5, 3],
]
```

Is there a better way than this?

var sizes = [61, 88, 67, 42, 45, 25, 49, 50, 39, 72, 49, 49, 81, 94, 95, 67, 44, 26, 46, 134, 69, 78, 86, 48, 85, 47, 88, 86, 59, 77, 120, 69, 38, 62, 42, 57, 48, 131, 137, 21, 92, 75, 40, 39, 40, 42, 36, 43, 66, 80, 72, 72, 52, 91, 80, 65, 89, 69, 64, 48, 83, 81, 78, 123, 67, 103, 75, 43, 54, 47, 28, 44, 64, 58, 53, 57, 80, 65, 40, 76, 57]

```
var nums = [3, 5, 7]

var designs = []
var i = sizes.length
while (i--) {
  designs.push(make())
}

console.log(designs)

function make() {
  var size = sizes.shift()
  return size % 2 === 0
    ? makeEven(size)
    : makeOdd(size)
}

function makeEven(total) {
  var start = []
  var end = []
  var half = total / 2
  while (half) {
    var num = nums[rand(0, 2)]
    var res = half - num
    if (res < 0) return makeEven(total)
    half = half - num
    start.push(num)
    end.unshift(num)
  }
  var result = start.concat(end)
  return result
}

function makeOdd(total) {
  var middle = nums[rand(0, 2)]
  var start = []
  var end = []
  var half = (total - middle) / 2
  while (half) {
    var num = nums[rand(0, 2)]
    var res = half - num
    if (res < 0) return makeOdd(total)
    half = half - num
    start.push(num)
    end.unshift(num)
  }
  var result = start.concat([ middle ]).concat(end)
  return result
}

function rand(min, max) { // min and max included
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
```

Comment: I think you can separate them in three category left aligned, center aligned and right aligned, then it will be easy to manipulate the spaces easily.

Comment: i.e bow is left aligned you need not to add any extra space you can just simply print the row. the first one is center aligned so first find maximum length, then row which has length less than max just add space at start or end based on orientation ( max length /2 ) - (length of current row /2 )